# dispatch_get_main_queue() not update UI when move from oneViewController to another ViewController and back again

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

In my application i perform long task in background. So i used `Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)` and update the UI in main Queue.

Here is my code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0), {
    // perform long task
    //update UI   
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
           self.Label.text = "value changed"  // not work
           self.collectionView.reloadData() // work properly
        })    
})
```

It will work fine. However  when i move from my current `ViewController` to `NextViewController` and again back to`ViewController` background task is executed but my `Label` will not change.

**QUESTION**:  Please help me so i can update my UI when back from another ViewController

**NOTE:** for moving one ViewController to another the task is perform in main queue.

**EDIT :**  here is a output of @Yuri code

```
2015-06-08 14:34:19.565 myApp[7726:1481939]  before: self:Logic() `self.label:<myApp.ViewController: 0x15947e00>

2015-06-08 14:34:50.925 myApp[7726:1481925]  after: self:Logic() self.label:<myApp.ViewController: 0x15947e00>`
```

**Edit2**  here is output of   @Oyeoj

```
before: <UILabel: 0x16565c60; frame = (20 56; 104 18); text = 'Back up'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x16565eb0>>
after: <UILabel: 0x16565c60; frame = (20 56; 104 18); text = 'value changed'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x16565eb0>>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling [self.Label setNeedsDisplay] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates of UI must be made in main thread, it is likely that your updates in UI will not work..

try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0), {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

         println("before: \(self.Label)")

         self.collectionView.reloadData() 

         self.Label.text = "value changed"

         self.Label.setNeedsDisplay() // don't forget this line..

         println("after: \(self.Label)")
    })    
})
```

**Edit 1**

Okay, i'm down voted can i at least know why? just for my edification, thank you..

From your @edit2 log, it seems that the values of `self.Label.text` was updated but your UIViewController was not in control of the main thread..

and i will recommend you to use `NSNotificationCenter` to trigger the updates in you `ViewController`

it'll look like this now:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "methodReceiver:", name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0), {
    //long task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

         // sends notification to `methodReceiver` 
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
    })    
})

@objc func methodReceiver(notification: NSNotification){

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        self.collectionView.reloadData() 

        self.Label.text = "value changed"

        self.Label.setNeedsDisplay() // don't forget this line..

    })


    // in case you want to remove the Observer after notification was delivered 
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
}
```

Hope this have helped you for some reason..

**Edit 2**

from comment: 
`this approach is work , but i want to know why my UIViewController is not in controll of main thread`

Inside your

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0)`

your are processing in background (long task) and will not block any main thread activity...

then you changed to `AnotherUIViewController` which has `UI` updates, now your main thread is in `AnotherUIViewController`'s control while `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(` is still in progress, then let's say you go back to `UIViewController` then `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {` was fired, BUT tasks inside `AnotherUIViewController` was not yet done,

like for example:

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // -> (in objective-C code)`

or any other UI updates that is currently in progress will be handled first before `UIViewController` takes control of main thread again since all dispatch queues are FIFO..

that's how it works i believe..

for more information about that heres [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) from apple..

Comment: in my opinion problem is moving from viewContoller is also done in mainthread

Comment: this approach is work , but i want to know why my UIViewController is not in controll of main thread

Comment: thanks for your explanation.  can u send me the link of objective c example

Answer (score 0):

Check pointers, are they the same?

My be block never called?

```
NSLog(@"%s before: self:%@ self.label:%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self, self.Label);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0), {
       // perform long task
       //update UI   
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          self.Label.text = "value changed"
          NSLog(@"%s after: self:%@ self.label:%@", ____PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self, self.Label);        
       })    
})
```

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {} block is called but my Ui is not updated

Comment: @RizwanShaikh can you please run code provided by Yuri and post NSLog output ?

Comment: i used swift there is no ____PRETTY_FUNCTION__